# YouTube Data API Maximum queries quota per day decreased to 0 and cannot set any number

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Our projects queries quota limit per day suddenly decreased to 0 without any explanation by Google.

We are using YouTube Data API for our project and are almost releasing the app. So we requested YouTube to increase the limitation of queries quota per day. However, three days later it was decreased to 0 without any clear explanation or notification. We are wondering if this is because the app violates any guidelines(We believe it doesn't) of API or because of any bugs.

We understand this is not the question about programming but seems like StackOverflow is the only channel we can contact them about YouTube Data API.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support?hl=ja

Would be really appreciated if anyone could provide us any information regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you have missed a few emails.  You probably got several telling you that you would need to apply for a quota extension before a specific date.   If you did not your quota would be reduced to 0.

You will now need to request a quota extension.  Once you have done that you will be able to use the api again.   There is no longer an automatic quota when created an application using the YouTube api.

It only took me a few days to get my quota back.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information!  
We checked email box carefully but haven't got any from them. We requested the quota extension on 14th(6 days ago), so we should probably wait for more several days.

Comment: @stella any progress for your problem? Currently I requested to acquire more quota using "YouTube Data API Services – Exceptions form", but the quota is reduce to 0 instead.

Comment: send the request again took a few weeks to get a response