# YouTube API requests failing due to "Access Not Configured" (also: "queries per day" quota is locked to 0)

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota, google-developers-console

No matter what we try, all YouTube API requests we make are failing.

As we first thought this was a propagation issue, we waited out 10 minutes, then 30 minutes, 2 hours and now over 24 hours, to no avail.

We have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221425/youtube-data-api-maximum-queries-quota-per-day-decreased-to-0-and-cannot-set-any), which covers a similar issue with an iOS app, but does not correspond to our use case.

Here is a run-down of what the problem is:

1. Activating the "Youtube Data API v3" API for our account shows as successful, and the API shows as enabled.
2. A `POST` to `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos` (videos insert) consistently fails with the following error, despite the fact that we have waited hours for the API enabling to propagate:

   `Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=928939889952 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.`
3. Although the error does not directly point to this, our "Queries per day" quota for the YouTube Data API is showing as "0". We are not able to understand why this is showing as zero, and unfortunately, all attempts to edit it to something higher have failed, and disabling and then re-enabling the API has not solved the problem. In a completely separate project/account, this shows as "10,000" when enabling the YouTube Data API, and indeed video insert API calls work under that project.

This is a significant roadblock for us, as it prevents us from deploying our application: any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> No access configured

Actually means that you dont have permission to access the api.  It basically means you have enabled the api but dont have the quota to use it.  Its different then the you have run out of quota error message.

After a strange change sometime last year by default the quota for the Youtube api is now 0.  You need to request a quota extension it can take anywhere between a week to several months to get permission to use it.

It took me three months.   No i dont have any idea how they expect anyone to develop a new application without any quota and to know ahead of time that they need to apply for quota in order to start developing their application.  Its quite frustrating.

Comment: Facing the same problem. I saw the form that Google asks us to fill and it is totally insane in term of details, most of them being redundant. It's like Google decided to close its YouTube API almost completely. Unbelievable.